# facebook desktop problem with WWW::Facebook::API

Tags: perl, facebook

I am beginner and trying to develop facebook desktop apps with below code

```
use WWW::Facebook::API;
use Data::Dumper;

my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(
     desktop => 1,
     api_key => '******',
     secret => '******',

  );
my $token = $client->auth->login( browser => 'firefox', sleep => 15 );

my $friends_perl = $client->friends->get();
print Dumper $friends_perl;
```

**It is giving 'error_code' => 102 ie session key is not getting value**

**Thanks** in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of better-late-than-never, I highly recommend you take a look at the [Facebook::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Facebook-Graph/) library instead of WWW::Facebook::API. "Graph" is the newest API rolled out by Facebook, and I attended a [meeting](http://www.madmongers.org/talks/writing-facebook-apps-in-10-minutes-or-less) where the author of Facebook::Graph explained why his implementation was better than the older library.